# check whether some folder presented in path

Tags: python

I am iterating of folders and read files line by line in order to find some substring.

The problem is that I want to ignore some folders during search (like `bin` or `build`).

I tried to add check - but it still include it in the search

```
def step(ext, dirname, names):
    for name in names:
        if name.lower().endswith(".xml") or name.lower().endswith(".properties") or name.lower().endswith(".java"):
            path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
            if not "\bin\"" in path and not "\build" in path:
                with open(path, "r") as lines:
                    print "File: {}".format(path)
                    i = 0
                    for line in lines:
                        m = re.search(r"\{[^:]*:[^\}]*\}", line)
                        with open("search-result.txt", "a") as output:
                            if m is not None:
                                output.write("Path: {0}; \n    Line number: {1}; \n        String: {2}\n".format(path, i, m.group()))
                        i+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your condition is failing because `\b` is being interpreted as the backspace character, rather than a backslash character followed by a "b" character. Also, it looks like you're escaping a quote mark at the end of bin; is that intentional?

Try escaping the backslashes.

```
if not "\\bin\\" in path and not "\\build" in path:
```

Comment: I am not if OP runs this code on Windows. Probably he should use `os.path.sep` instead of `'\\'`

Answer (score 1):

[Kevins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30102300/1149736) will do the job, but I prefer to let [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/os.path.html) do this job (so if anyone ever uses the function on different platform it will work):

```
import os.path

def path_contains(path, folder):
    while path:
        path, fld = os.path.split(path)
        # Nothing in folder anymore? Check beginning and quit
        if not fld:
            if path == folder:
                return True
            return False

        if fld == folder:
            return True

    return False


>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'system32')
True
>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'windows')
False
>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'Windows')
True
>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'C:\\')
True
>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'C:')
False
>>> path_contains(r'C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe', 'test')
False
```